# Getting error in ActionsScript for a file that doesn't exist and that file is tempInit

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, animate-cc

So, I'm converting a flash file from 10 years ago that used actionscript 2.0.  Now, I'm down to the last two errors but the top and bottom ones don't exist and the errors regarding bytes_loader are invalid.

Here are the errors:

[image]

Here are the errors listed here that are in the picture in the order of their appearance:

```
tempInit, Line 1, Column 15 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before ECHO.
tempInit, Line 2, Column 15 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before flowin.
Symbol 'bytes_loader', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 4, Column 22  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before leftbrace.
Symbol 'bytes_loader', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 2, Line 8, Column 23  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before leftbrace.
tempInit, Line 1, Column 15 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before implode.
tempInit, Line 1, Column 15 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before lightflash.
```

Now the code for the two that I can get to in bytes_loader;

UPDATE:

1. added line numbers as it appears in the action editor
2. Identified that tempInit does not exist anywhere in the action editor
3. the first frame in the movie is "STOP" then SYMBOL DEFINITIONS then the very first element is: bytes_loader with its three frames.
4. That's all there is...

   1) frloaded = _root.getBytesLoaded();
   2) frtotal = _root.getBytesTotal();
   3) if (frloaded < frtotal) {
   4)     tellTarget("_root") {
   5)      stop();
   6)     }
   7) }

AND

```
1) frloaded = _root.getBytesLoaded();
2) frtotal = _root.getBytesTotal();
3) if (frloaded < frtotal) {
4)  percentloaded = int((frloaded / frtotal) * 100) + "%";
5)  setProperty("wbar", _xscale, (frloaded/frtotal) * 100);
6)  setProperty("bbar", _xscale, (frloaded/frtotal) * 100);
7) } else {
8)  tellTarget ("_root") {
9)      play();
10)     }
11) }
```

The reference to tempInit I can't find.

So, what's wrong with the code that doesn't error out...

Comment: **(1)** Why not paste the errors text into your question? Akward to flip between photo and  question page. **(2)** Why not click the error itself? Does it take you to some line where you typed "tempInit"? **(3)** Is `bytes_loader` a _MovieClip_ object? If yes, is that shown **AS2** code actually what you've used inside an (incompatible) **AS3** symbol/class?...

Comment: Show the lines of code that cause error, especially line 1 of **tempInit** code.

Comment: Sorry, but tempInit goes NOWHERE from that picture I embedded.  The lines of code will be shown in the UPDATE to this question.  So, VC One: There are no errors except that which show up when I run TEST in the CONTROL menu.  Sorry about the awkwardness. When I click on anything but the bytes_loader errors, the tempInit goes nowhere. Sorry. Even in the actions windows where all the AS code is, there is no tempInit to be found.  The code I pasted is 100% correct and there's no other errors or problems. bytes_loader is a preloader for the movie when it starts from frame one. More on UPDATE above.

Comment: Look in your **Library** (ctrl+L)... in there do you have any linkage / instance names with spaces in them? No spaces allowed (ie: use underscores). Try checking _linkage_ names first then if still error, try renaming any MC that has spaces.

Comment: Interesting... as this worked in the past until I started using Animate CC and it converted AS2 to AS3.... I see a TON... making changes and I'll report back.

Comment: NO JOY! Still have the same errors...

Comment: Are you aware that AS2 and AS3 are incompatible? You cannot just say "now this script is AS3" and hope it magically works. Google for migration guide.

Comment: No, I never said I hope it magically works.  No worries, however. I used another program to capture the flash video, embed a few cool updated slides on the beginning and end, added a new soundtrack and the voiceover track as an overlay and wala!!! It's an MP4 with very little effort using the <video> tag.  I guess that's why I haven't programmed in Flash since 2004.  I'm good now.